# Why are the sizes of 2 directories different if the data within the directories is identical? They are identical ext4 partitions and disks

Tags: linux, ext4

```
root@phoenix:~# ls -ld /backups/external?/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 73728 Mar  4 15:35 /backups/external3/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 69632 Mar  4 15:35 /backups/external4/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
```

The contents of the above directories is identical.  The disks and filesystem configurations are identical.  Yet the sizes of the directories *themselves* are different.

Yes the contents of the directory in question are identical, i've checked with diff -r, rsync -avx as well as beyond compare.  Here's diff -r output:

```
root@phoenix:~# diff -r /backups/external{3,4}/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
root@phoenix:~#
```

du -bs output:

```
root@phoenix:~# du -bs /backups/external?/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
4116125 /backups/external3/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
4112029 /backups/external4/var/subsonic/thumbs/110
```

du -b --total output counting *just the files within each directory*:

```
root@phoenix:~# du -b --total /backups/external3/var/subsonic/thumbs/110/* | tail -1 
4042397 total
root@phoenix:~# du -b --total /backups/external4/var/subsonic/thumbs/110/* | tail -1 
4042397 total
```

So, for the external3:

```
4042397 + 73728 = 4116125
```

and for external4:

```
4042397 + 69632 = 4112029
```

The size of the files added to the size of the directory itself matches the output from du -bs.

Comment: This is where we ask how certain you are that the contents are the same.

Comment: Please see the edited question, yes, triple checked with various methods that the contents are the same.

Comment: Did you try `du -s`?

Comment: `-b` implies `--apparent-size`, which changes things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size reported by `ls -l` for a directory has no relationship with the cumulated size of files stored in it.

It is just, for most common file systems, the size in bytes that has been required to store the directory entries. This size grows by block size (eg: 4096, 8192, ...). How many entries can be stored in a block is file system dependent and vary also with entries filenames length.

When directory entries are removed, the directory size is unaffected to reduce fragmentation.

In your example, the `external3` directory has `18 * 4096` blocks allocated while the `external4` has `17 * 4096` blocks.

That just means the former stored once more files (or files with longer names) even while the directory contents are currently identical. No big deal.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i suspected and hoped to be confirmed.